# CName DNS Redirect not working

Tags: azure, dns, cname

I am kind of lost as to why my Azure website is not correctly handling the domain name redirect for my site. It works for www.guardiancrosstrading.com but not guardiancrosstrading.com.

What's annoying is that it clearly is set up to redirect:
http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=cname%3aguardiancrosstrading.com&run=toolpage#

And in azure I have both guardiancrosstrading.com and www.guardiancrosstrading.com listed under custom domains, so I am pretty lost as to what the issue is.

Anyone have any tips or ideas of what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

CNAME does not work for the root domain (ie. the non-www domain).  You will need to use domain forwarding to forward guardiancrosstrading.com to www.guardiancrosstrading.com, at which point the client will follow the CNAME redirect to your cloudapp.net URL.  Whoever owns your guardiancrosstrading.com domain name should have a feature to allow root domain redirects.